# CSS changes when template loaded from ngView (Vegas slideshow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am implementing simple web page where I would like to have **main page with full screen slider** (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) and some content below. On the other hand I would like to have additional view where I would like to disable full screen and just have some other content.

I am using Angular project generated via yeoman https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular and some free available bootstrap template.

**Eveything is working great when I put all my main page code into index.html** (where I have all the bower components, css, custom scripts) - vegas slideshow displays on full screen and i have content above it.

[image]

**However - when I move main page content (vegas slideshow + content) into angular view (let's called it mani) leaving just navbar menu, footer etc in index.hmtl, CSS seems to be broken as vegas slideshow now does not covers full screen but just piece of it.** - you can see that content (black background div) is displayed whereas full screen should be present + image is moved to the top/truncated.

[image]

I assume it's related to order to rendering (angular tempalte is loaded asynchronusly most probably), I've tried movign things around, running vegas after document is ready but no success.

Piece of code:

**index.html**

```
 <body ng-app="semApp" id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
    your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                <span class="light">Isabel</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#/#about">O nas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="/#/#download">Download</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<div ng-view=""></div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**main.html:**

```
<!-- Intro Header -->
<header class="intro">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container middlePage">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h1 class="brand-heading">Isabel</h1>
          <p class="intro-text">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Kolekcja 2016</a></p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Download Section -->
<section id="download" class="content-section text-center">
  <div class="download-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h2>Download Grayscale</h2>
        <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the preview page at Start Bootstrap.</p>
        <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit Download Page</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".intro-body").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "images/1.jpg" },
        { src: "images/2.jpg" }
    ]
});
});
</script>
```

**css:**

```
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Grayscale Bootstrap Theme (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato); /* FREE GOOGLE FONTS */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel|Great+Vibes);

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    p {
        margin: 0 0 35px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
}

a {
    color: #42dca3;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1d9b6c;
}

.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover {
    outline: 0;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-custom {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background: #000;
    }
}

.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.logo-about {
    height: 100px;
}

.middlePage {
    padding-top: 20%;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
}

.btn-circle {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%!important;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #000;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.content-section {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.download-section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../images/downloads-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .content-section {
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .download-section {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

    #map {
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 250px;
    }
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid (0,0,0,.2);
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

ul.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media(max-width:1199px) {
    ul.banner-social-buttons {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    ul.banner-social-buttons li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.banner-social-buttons li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

footer {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

img::selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

Any help apprieciated!

---

**UPDATE - JSFiddle link**: http://jsfiddle.net/qtkfq2d7/

Comment: post your code in Jsfiddle or codepen for better view.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qtkfq2d7/

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue.